# Multi-processing in python for solving PDEs

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am solving a partial differential equation called Navier-Stokes equation using python. This problem is a time-dependent problem which means that the solution is being carried out step by step, and each step is used as initial condition for the next step (basically it is for loop solution).

I have realized that the python code is using only one CPU while solving, and I would like to accelerate this process and I have a dual-core processor (4-logical processors). So my question: Is there any way to solve each time step using 2 or three CPUs, I mean can I use two CPUs to solve the first time step, then the two CPUS to solve the second and so one.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out some existing packages, such as [Oasis.](https://www.groundai.com/project/oasis-a-high-levelhigh-performance-open-source-navier-stokes-solver/1)